# Add Google service credentials to Android App for connect Google Cloud

Tags: android, oauth, google-cloud-platform, credentials, google-text-to-speech

In my app I need to use Google Cloud Text to Speech. I add sdk via gralde 
      implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-texttospeech:0.100.0-beta'.

After that i am not understanding how to add credentials to my android app. In Cloud console I created and added billing for project and downloaded service account json file. But where can i add in android app ? If i run code without adding the app I'm getting an exception

> " The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are
>   available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the
>   environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined
>   pointing to a file defining the credentials. See
>   https://developers.google  "

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech

Here you can see how to add credentials

Below is a TTS sample project that I created with reference to Google Cloud STT

https://github.com/ivso0001/GoogleCloudTextToSpeech/tree/master